# I can start the same build definitions multiple times and they are processed parallel, how can I deny this behavior?

Tags: tfs, build, vnext

I have created a vNext build definition in TFS 2018. I'm able to queue this 
build definition many times and they were processed parallel.

This behaviour is not acceptable. If they are processed in order, I can live with it.

Does anyone know which setting I have to setup in the definition?

I'm running a tfs in following environment:

TFS 2018.2 On-Premise
4 Build-Agents with different capabilities
1 Build-Definition which fulfills the capabilities of all agents

It is planned, to have more build definitions. Today, we have only one because we are migrating our xaml-builds to vNext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Triggers tab, check the "Batch Changes While Build is in Progress" option and set the number of concurrent builds to 1.

However, I would strongly recommend fixing whatever prevents your builds from running in parallel. Builds should ideally be stateless and have no impact on one another.

You can also set a custom Demand/Capability pair such that only one of your agents satisfies your build definition's requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but i have no option to setup the concurrent builds (in both trigger: CI or Scheduled). I know, this was possible in an earlier version.

Comment: The best solution is to fix the build so they can run in parallel.